# SparkSQL : Intervals greater than a month doesn't make any sense

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

SparkSQL: Intervals greater than a month doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 3):

Since intervals larger than one month are ambiguous, you should express them in more precise units. It means you should replace

```scala
window(rawdataDS.col("date_time_epoch"),"1 month")
```

with

```scala
window(rawdataDS.col("date_time_epoch"),"30 days")
```

or whatever value you consider a month.

Reference [Maximum interval for o.a.s.sql.functions.window](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/SQL-SPARK-14160-Maximum-interval-for-o-a-s-sql-functions-window-td20655.html)  on the [Apache Spark developers list](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/).

If you want to summarize your data by a calendar month `window` won't be useful for you. Instead you should rather use one of the following:

- `trunc(col, "month")` (see for example [How to compute the sum of orders over a 12 months period sliding by 1 month...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47531381/10465355)).
- `date_trunc("month", col)` (see for example [How do I truncate a PySpark dataframe of timestamp type to the day?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49948277/10465355)).